# Date and time format

Tags: time

How to echo date and time like this [day-month-year/hour-minutes-seconds] including "[" and "/". I also need to redirect it in a file. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look at `date --help`:

```
Usage: date [OPTION]... [+FORMAT]
```

and it gives a list of date format specifiers.

To get the format you want (assuming you want local time, and all fields padded with zeroes, 24-hour time), use the format specifier `[%d-%m-%Y/%H-%M-%S]`. That is, run

```
username@host:/path$ date '+[%d-%m-%Y/%H-%M-%S]'
[19-12-2012/17-16-16]
```

To redirect to a file, use standard shell redirection (`date '+[%d-%m-%Y/%H-%M-%S]' > filename` to overwrite the file, or `date '+[%d-%m-%Y/%H-%M-%S]' >> filename` to append).

Comment: And if I want to put some text before the date. EX: my_text [date/time]